# Filtering array of objects with multiple properties getting empty as result

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

Here is my try to get result with multiple properties. but getting always empty array as result.

any one show me correct and minimal approach here? I have no.of different filter criteria too..

```
nestedFilter = (targetArray, filters) => {
          var filterKeys = Object.keys(filters);
          return targetArray.filter(function (eachObj) {
            return filterKeys.every(function (eachKey) {
              return filters[eachKey].includes(eachObj[eachKey]);
           });
       });
    };

//filter 1    
let filter1 = {
  color: "Blue",
  size:'70'
};
//filter 2
let filter2 = {
  name:'',
  color: "Blue",
  size:'70'
};

//filter 3
let filters = {
    name:'',
  color: "",
  size:''
};


let products = [
  { name: "A", color: "Blue", size: 50 },
  { name: "B", color: "Blue", size: 60  },
  { name: "C", color: "Black", size: 70 },
  { name: "D", color: "Green", size: 50 },
];

var results = nestedFilter(products, filter2);

console.log(results); //getting alwasy empty.
```

[Live Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/d54gvs6z/1/)

Comment: You don't have any product with  empty name

Comment: @CodeManiac - please check i have multiple filter criteria.

Comment: You're searching in `filters[eachKey].includes(eachObj[eachKey])` which is always false, as none of your key in filter is having values

Comment: in your filter you have `name: ''` so you none of products is having name as `""` so what is desired result in such case

Comment: @CodeManiac - instead of `includes` i tried with `contains` but still no luck

Comment: @such case `name` should not be consider. when there is no value let it skip!!

Comment: So you want those values in output which matches atleast one of value from filter ?

Comment: Can you please explain how your code should work? It's fairly confusing right now.

Comment: @CodeManiac - yes. you are correct. as per me `filterKeys.every` is not works as expected. this is all about user. we can't restrict them. they can add some value or may leave as empty in input text.

Comment: @user2024080 you need to use `some` not `every`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some as you want product to be included in output if any one value matches

```js
let products = [{name: "A",color: "Blue",size: 50},{name: "B",color: "Blue",size: 60},{name: "C",color: "Black",size: 70},{name: "D",color: "Green",size: 50},];


let filter1 = {color: "Blue",size: '70'};
let filter2 = {name: '',color: "Blue",size: '70'};
let filters = {name: '',color: "",size: ''};

const nestedFilter = (targetArray, filters) => {
  var filterKeys = Object.keys(filters);
  return targetArray.filter(function(eachObj) {
    return filterKeys.some(function(eachKey) {
      return filters[eachKey].includes(eachObj[eachKey]);
    });
  });
};


console.log(nestedFilter(products, filter1))
console.log(nestedFilter(products, filter2))
console.log(nestedFilter(products, filters))
```

Comment: actually `console.log(nestedFilter(products, filters))` need to return all. should consider there is no filter at all.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `some` not `every`. Also note you can take advantage of nested returns and other features to make your code more concise.

```js
const nestedFilter = (targetArray, filters) => targetArray.filter(o => Object.keys(filters).some(k => filters[k].includes(o[k]) || filters[k] == ""));
 
let filter1 = {color:"Blue",size:'70'};
let filter2 = {name:'',color:"Blue",size:'70'};
let filters = {name:'',color:"",size:''};
let products = [{name:"A",color:"Blue",size:50},{name:"B",color:"Blue",size:60},{name:"C",color:"Black",size:70},{name:"D",color:"Green",size:50},];

console.log(nestedFilter(products, filter1));
console.log(nestedFilter(products, filter2));
console.log(nestedFilter(products, filters));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: where there is no filter all are empty like `filters` - i needs all objects returned instead of empty.

Comment: Instead of matching any criteria using some, can you update to mach all criteria? for the what the method need to use?

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this also with [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) 
 and [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) like this:

```js
let products = [
  { name: "A", color: "Blue", size: 50 },
  { name: "B", color: "Blue", size: 60  },
  { name: "C", color: "Black", size: 70 },
  { name: "D", color: "Green", size: 50 },
];

let filter1 = { color: 'Blue', size:  '70' }
let filter2 = { name:  '', color: 'Blue', size:  '60' }
let filter3 = { name:  '', color: '', size:  '' }

let nestedFilter = (arr, filter) => {
  let fE = Object.entries(filter)
  return arr.filter(f => fE.some(([k,v]) => !v || f[k].toString().includes(v)))
}

console.log(nestedFilter(products, filter1))  // 3 objects
console.log(nestedFilter(products, filter2))  // 4 objects
console.log(nestedFilter(products, filter3))  // 4 objects
```

The idea is to get the `entries` of the filter you are working with and then use its key/value to check if first there is no value which is `true` for us (we want records which filter key matches with empty string) and if the actual value matches the value of the current filtered object key.